# How to preserve jelly bean button design on ginger bread

Tags: java, android

I'm new in android programming, I install ADT and SDK level 17. when I set target level 2.2, the design is change, espescially button design

I want to make default button jelly bean design run in all of api level. is that possible? how can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a library such as [HoloEverywhere](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere), which backports the 'Holo' theme from ICS+ devices (such as Jelly Bean) to older devices.

Comment: @ForoTesto - be sure to accept this answer if it helped you answer your question!